# Can I use “see”+that-clause like this?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I found the footprints of a dinosaur, and I see them. In this case, can I say like this?

> “I can see that a dinosaur walked here.”

see: to be conscious of what is around you by using your eyes:

I also wonder why “that a dinosaur walked here is seen” doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct and natural. In this construction, **see** is an example of a *reporting verb.* Reporting verbs are usually followed by a noun clause introduced with **that**. The following all work the same way:

> I know that a dinosaur walked here.
> Scientists believe that a dinosaur walked here.
> My sister said that a dinosaur walked here.

"that a dinosaur walked here" is the object of the verbs **see, know, believe** and **said**.

The following does in fact make sense:

> that a dinosaur walked here is seen

But most native speakers would never say such a thing, and popular style manuals advise against such structures in writing.

I could make up a lot of psychological reasons why we don't speak this way, but they would ignore the fact that similar structures are common in other languages. If a native English speaker really wanted to add the "seen" idea to the claim, and really did not want to explain who did the "seeing," they would probably say this:

> It can be seen that a dinosaur walked here.